# Add icon to select2 not based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for creating nice dropdowns. Now, I am searching for a way to add icons / images to the dropdown elements. I want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#iconStyledDropdown').select2();
    });
</script>    

<select id="iconStyledDropdown">
    <option value="firstIcon"><span class="icon1"></span>First icon</option>
    <option value="anotherFirstIcon"><span class="icon1"></span>Another first icon</option>
    <option value="secondIcon"><span class="icon2"></span>Second icon</option>
    <option value="lastEntry"><span class="icon2"></span>Last entry</option>
</select>
```

I know the [dropdown templating documentation article](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) but this styling is based on the text / value of the option. I need a way to define the icons manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `class` to the option itself if that is possible. You can then use `state.element.className` to get the correct icon

```
<select id="iconStyledDropdown">
<option value="firstIcon" class="icon1">First icon</option>
<option value="anotherFirstIcon" class="icon1">Another first icon</option>
<option value="secondIcon" class="icon2">Second icon</option>
<option value="lastEntry"class="icon2">Last entry</option>
```

Then change the template for results to use the className to get the correct icon.

```
function addIcon(option) {
  var baseUrl = "/user/pages/images/flags";
  return $('<span><img src="' + baseUrl + '/' +
            option.element.className.toLowerCase() + '.png"/> ' +
            option.text + '</span>');
}
```

Your init code will look like this:

```
$('#iconStyledDropdown').select2({
   templateResult: addIcon
 });
```